# Cannot create a reusable login on python

Tags: python-2.7

I am attempting to create a login system for a quiz program but am unable to get the outcome I want. The first function creates a file for the user so that I can later save their details onto it - however this is not the part I'm struggling with and is only there for reference. The bit that I cannot get to work is in the second function where I see if the 1st line of the users file is equal to the string that they have inputted(the password) as it always tells me that they are not equal so the program does not let the user save data onto their created file because the passwords do not match. Please could you tell me how I can fix this issue.

```
def create_login(): 
YorN = "nothing"
while YorN != "y":
    name = raw_input(str("please input full name:"))
    age = raw_input(str("please input age:"))
    username = name[0:3] + age
    password = raw_input(str("please enter password:"))
    print "Are you sure you want to proceed with the username and password you have selected?"
    YorN = (raw_input("Please select Y or N:")).lower()
f = open(username +".txt","w+")
f.write(password)
f.write("\n")
f.write(name)
f.write("\n")
f.write(age)
f.write("\n")
f.write(username)
f.write("\n")
f.close()

def login():
    inp_username = raw_input(str("Please input your username:"))
    inp_password = raw_input(str("Please input your password:"))
    t = open(inp_username +".txt","r")
    lines = t.readlines()
    g = lines[0]
    if inp_password == g:
        print "Access Granted!"
    else:
        print "incorrect password"
        login_or_create()
```

Comment: `.readlines()` returns strings with a trailing newline character.  You need to strip that off before comparing with the user's input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The problem:

Each line in a text file ends in a `newline` character. When you read in a line or lines, each of them still has that newline character attached.

But, your passwords do not end in newline characters do not match:

```
password => 'mypassword'
line_read_in_from_file => 'mypassword\n'
```

## Solution:

`strip()` off the newline characters prior to doing the comparison, using the `.strip()` function that is associated with Python strings...

```
def login():
    inp_username = raw_input(str("Please input your username:"))
    inp_password = raw_input(str("Please input your password:"))
    t = open(inp_username +".txt","r")
    lines = t.readlines()

    # lines[0] is a string and as a string, has a function called .strip()

    g = lines[0].strip()
    if inp_password == g:
        print "Access Granted!"
    else:
        print "incorrect password"
        login_or_create()
```

Answer (score 0):

Strip the \n from lines[0] and make sure you are telling the username to your users i.e name[0:3]+age is the username.